# Find key array / sub_array php

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to get the key of an array but the function key () is not enough.
I have a table of the type:

```
array(
 0 => array(
   'id'=>'2',
   'name'=>'fe'
 ),
1 => array(
   'id'=>'3',
   'name'=>'fz'
 ),
)
```

I would like to retrieve the name according to the id. For example, know that table id 1 is named 'fe'.
I do not know how to do that, I thought to get the index (in my example 0 then do an array [index] ["name"] but I can not do it
Can you give me some leads please?
Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is not working with the given example?

Comment: "know that table id 1 is named 'fe'. " - in your example the id is 2?